# AssemblyLoadContext did not unload correctly

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have weird problem with method `Unload` in `AssemblyLoadContext`. Original code is from https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/22221/files/a7cbc5c8d1bd48cafec48ac50900ff9e96c1485c#diff-cf594171be5712641ea4416aadc2f83f and I am using dotnet core 3.0.100-preview3-010431

It works excellent in this case:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

namespace example
{
    class TestAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        public TestAssemblyLoadContext() : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName name)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    class Manager
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void Execute(out WeakReference testAlcWeakRef)
        {
            var alc = new TestAssemblyLoadContext();
            testAlcWeakRef = new WeakReference(alc);
            alc.Resolving += (alc2, assemblyName) =>
            {
                var dllName = assemblyName.Name.Split(',').First();
                return alc2.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"absolute\path\lib.dll");
            };

            Assembly a = alc.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"absolute\path\lib.dll");
            var args = new object[] { 3, 2 };

            var methodInfo = a.GetExportedTypes()[0].GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "MethodName").ToList()[0];
            var result = methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(a.GetExportedTypes()[0]), args);
            alc.Unload();
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void Unload(WeakReference testAlcWeakRef)
        {
            for (int i = 0; testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive && (i < 10); i++)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"is alive: {testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var manager = new Manager();
            manager.Execute(out var testAlcWeakRef);
            manager.Unload(testAlcWeakRef);
        }
    }
}
```

But I need call `Unload` method later. So I moved `alc.Unload()` into `manager.Unload()` and `alc.Unload()` is not working. What I am doing wrong?

Not working case:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

namespace example
{
    class TestAssemblyLoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        public TestAssemblyLoadContext() : base(true)
        {
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName name)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    class Manager
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void Execute(out WeakReference testAlcWeakRef, out TestAssemblyLoadContext alc)
        {
            alc = new TestAssemblyLoadContext();
            testAlcWeakRef = new WeakReference(alc);
            alc.Resolving += (alc2, assemblyName) =>
            {
                var dllName = assemblyName.Name.Split(',').First();
                return alc2.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"absolute\path\lib.dll");
            };

            Assembly a = alc.LoadFromAssemblyPath(@"absolute\path\lib.dll");
            var args = new object[] { 3, 2 };

            var methodInfo = a.GetExportedTypes()[0].GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "MethodName").ToList()[0];
            var result = methodInfo.Invoke(Activator.CreateInstance(a.GetExportedTypes()[0]), args);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public void Unload(WeakReference testAlcWeakRef, TestAssemblyLoadContext alc)
        {
            alc.Unload();
            for (int i = 0; testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive && (i < 10); i++)
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"is alive: {testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var manager = new Manager();
            manager.Execute(out var testAlcWeakRef, out var alc);
            manager.Unload(testAlcWeakRef, alc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did u get this working?

Comment: See comment below on answer.... why does this not work if you dnt specify ref key word, when by default it is a ref, makes no sense to me! highly annoying, add ref it works, take it out and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.unload?view=netcore-3.0):

> **Remarks**:
>
> - An AssemblyLoadContext can only be unloaded if it is collectible.
> - Unloading will occur asynchronously.
> - Unloading will not occur while there are references to the AssemblyLoadContext.

Your **alc** variable is preventing context from the unload.

Possible solution:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public void Unload(WeakReference testAlcWeakRef, ref TestAssemblyLoadContext alc)
{
    alc.Unload(); 
    alc = null;

    for (int i = 0; testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive && (i < 10); i++)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"is alive: {testAlcWeakRef.IsAlive}");
}
```

Comment: why does this not work if you dnt specify ref, when by default it is a ref, makes no sense to me! highly annoying, add ref it works, take it out and it doesn't.